# cmake std::shared_ptr CHECK_CXX_SOURCE_COMPILES fails mysql connector-c++ pre-build

Tags: c++11, cmake, mysql-connector

I'm trying to compile the MySQL Connector--C++ using their Git repo and CMake. I am new to CMake, so I just might not know. As it stands the code below fails, and fails as "Type std::shared_ptr required by CDK is not available". I'm using Visual Studio 2017, and can access a std::shared_ptr just fine. The header  is included. I'm at a loss.

```
set(CMAKE_REQUIRED_FLAGS "${CMAKE_REQUIRED_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

INCLUDE(CheckCXXSourceCompiles)

CHECK_CXX_SOURCE_COMPILES(
  "#include <memory>
   void test(std::shared_ptr<int>) {};
   int main() { return 0; }"
  HAVE_SHARED_PTR
)
#message("HAVE_SHARED_PTR: ${HAVE_SHARED_PTR}")
ADD_CONFIG(HAVE_SHARED_PTR)

if (NOT HAVE_SHARED_PTR)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Type std::shared_ptr required by CDK is not available")
endif()
```

Comment: was able to CHECK_CXX_SOURCE_COMPILES using the cmake tool downloaded from the cmake site and the vc compiler. i just need to point to the endian and bytecode header. seems reasonable enough. not the solution proper though.

Comment: Not sure if that is related, but in the past I've observed some very weird behavior when accidentally choosing Visual Studio 15 as generator for VS2015 instead of "Visual Studio 14 2015" (the correct one for VS2015, those version numbers are odd). Errors were showing up that didn't make any sense. Maybe you check against your generator again and do not forget to delete your cache!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received feedback from the MySQL bug reporting system. What CXX is under the hood, or isn't for that matter, in the vs ide, is not capable of compiling the test code using CHECK_CXX_SOURCE_COMPILES. The solution given was to check if the msvc compiler is at or above a certain build, where it could be guaranteed that the features are present. The alternative is to use either the cmake command line with the msvc compiler, or use the cmake gui tool, again with the msvc compiler. I would have just liked to have used the vs ide. There are also a couple issues with header files. It is suggested that you can take them directly from Boost, but only endian exists and not byteorder. My final solution is to use the .Net connector and interoping as the tasks involving MySQL are large and sequential, and not mission critical. and not overly affected by c#.